# Django Rest Framework invalid serializer data, can not figure out why

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am creating a simple model with a many-to-many field. The model works fine and I can create model through the admin panel, and I can make a get request to see that model (except that it only returns user IDs instead of the user models/objects). My problem is when creating a post request to create said model.

I get one of the two errors depending on the changes I make, `The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'str' instance.` or `AssertionError: You cannot call '.save()' on a serializer with invalid data.`, either way it has something to do with my serializer. The following is my model,

```
class Schema(models.Model):
    week = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, 
                                       unique=True,
                                       validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(53)],
                                       )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="users")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('week',)
```

My View,

```
class SchemaView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (SchemaPermissions,)

    def get(self, request):
        schemas = Schema.objects.all()
        serializer = SchemaSerializer(schemas, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        serializer = SchemaSerializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid()
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And my serializer,

```
class SchemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Schema
        fields = ('week', 'users')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        users_data = validated_data.pop('users')
        users = MyUser.objects.filter(id__in=users_data)
        schema = Schema.objects.create(week=validated_data.week, users=users)

        return schema

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        users_data = validated_data.pop('users')
        users = MyUser.objects.filter(id__in=users_data)
        instance.users.clear()
        instance.users.add(*users)
        instance.saver()
        return instance
```

The idea is that if a week number already exists then it should call the update() function and then it should simply overwrite the users related to that week number, otherwise it should call create() and create a new week number with relations to the given users. The following is the result of printing the serializer after initializing it in the view.

```
SchemaSerializer(data={'week': 32, 'users': [1, 2, 3]}):
    week = IntegerField(max_value=53, min_value=1, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Schema.objects.all())>])
    users = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_empty=False, many=True, queryset=MyUser.objects.all())
```

It seems to me that the serializer should be valid for the given model? I am perhaps missing some concepts and knowledge about Django and DRF here, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need set the field for saving `users` in the `SchemaSerializer`. And you don't need to customize the `create` and `update` method because the logic could be coded in the `views`.

```
class SchemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserSerializer(read_only = True, many = True)
    user_ids = serializers.ListField(
        child = serializers.IntegerField,
        write_only = True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Schema
        fields = ('week', 'users', 'user_ids',)

    # remove create and update method
```

And in views.py,

```
class SchemaView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (SchemaPermissions,)

    def get(self, request):
        ...

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        serializer = SchemaSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            input_data = serializer.validated_data
            week = input_data.get('week')
            user_ids = input_data.get('user_ids')
            if Schema.objects.filter(week = week).count() > 0:
                schema = Schema.objects.get(week = week).first()
            else:
                schema = Schema.objects.create(week = week)
            schema.users.set(user_ids)
            schema.save()
        
            return Response(SchemaSerializer(schema).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            print(serializer.errors)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And of course, the payload data should be

```
{'week': 23, 'user_ids': [1,2,3]}
```

Comment: Hey I tried your suggestion, it somewhat works I guess. When I create a new Schema (with a week number that does not exist), then it seems to create the model correctly, and when I do a get request, I get the expected. However it still produces the following error `TypeError: Schema() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_ids'` and something about a writable field and perhaps it should be read only or I need to make a .create() method. If the week number already exists then the .is_valid() check fails. Again any ideas why, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you just use my code? Or change a little bit?

Comment: I pretty much used your code. I tried changing things when I couldn't get it to work, but otherwise no

Comment: I can't see the changed code you wrote, so please show me the code you changed.

Comment: I simply tried changing the user_ids field in the serializer to have `read_only = True`, since I got an error that hinted towards that, this error ` TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `Schema.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Schema.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the SchemaSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly. `

Comment: `user_ids` field doesn't exist in the model so you shouldn't set `read_only = True`. It's just for getting data from the request payload with the key named 'user_ids'.

Comment: Right that makes sense. Any idea why then? Because I am quite lost

Comment: What do you mean? I think my answer is correct. So can you please accept my answer and post a new question? So that I could answer there.

Comment: Okay, might be. But it still does not work 100% though. As mentioned on POST request I still get an error, and when the week number already exists in the database then the `.is_valid()` returns false, thus it give a 400 error

Comment: I added the line `print(serializer.errors)` and changed the next line, so that you could check what errors. Could you show me the errors?

Comment: `{'week': [ErrorDetail(string='schema with this week already exists.', code='unique')]}`. So yea it seems like it tries to create the row again

Comment: Okay, it seems to be because you set the `unique` attribute in the `week` field in the `Schema` model. So please remove that attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247286/discussion-between-metalgear-and-wardz).